# Can we loop feature files and execute using multiple login users in karate

Tags: karate

For our project requirement we have to run the feature file using 50 users .
For now I am able to run using one user which is configured in the karate.config file.
I need to configure these 50 users in the config file and run the same feature file for all 50 users.
Looking for a way to configure all users in one config file and run the feature file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my suggestion.

Don't overload your config file like this.

Use a JSON file with an array of users.

Now you can read this JSON file from any feature using the `read` syntax.

And you can use Karate's built-in looping capability to do what you need: https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features

```
* def users = read('users.json')
* def result = call read('user-test.feature') users
```