# Karate-API ~ Using karate's environment variable to pass into Java Faker class

Tags: java, karate

The scenario:

I have java faker set up to create email address for each of my karate tests.
example:

```
    Faker faker = new Faker();
    String email = "people-service." + faker.random().nextInt(0, 100000000)
        + "@mail.com";
    return email;
```

I run my tests via command line
(example: qa-people-service % mvn clean test Dkarate.env=sqa -Dkarate.options="--tags @play"

is there a way I can pass in the environment variable run in the command line into my email addresses?
e.g.

```
String email = "<Dkarate.env>" + "people-service." + faker.random().nextInt(0, 100000000)
        + "@mail.com";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you add `-DmyKey=myValue`

You can do this anywhere in Karate (feature or JS):

```
* def myKey = karate.properties['myKey']
```

Also refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52821230/143475