# How to Pass Input variables to Karate file via npm?

Tags: javascript, npm, karate

I have a test script which execute some set of queries, to execute the file, inputs like url and auth header are needed which will differ for each environment

So, I need to get those inputs from user, how to get these inputs as part of command to execute the karate file.

Background:

- Given url `<url>`
- header Authorization = `<token>`

Instead of hardcoding the url and token, this has to be get from user

Answer (score 0):

Please read up on how to switch environments in Karate first: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#switching-the-environment

This requires you to understand how to use a file called [`karate-config.js`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#karate-configjs). You can place it in the root of your working folder or you can [specify the location on the command-line](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-npm#karate-configjs).

So passing `-e e2e` as a command-line argument will set the `karate.env` to `e2e`.

If you really want to get extra values from the environment or command-line, please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52821230/143475