# Embedded expressions not replaced if surrounded by dot and underscores in it

Tags: karate

The embedded expressions are not replaced when appended, prepended or surrounded by characters in the following way

```
* def RADName = 'IntegrationFirstRAD'
* def tenantID = '1452119626'

* def out = 
        """
       {
    "nsName": "fld_<tenantID>_stage00.rad.<RADName>_.resources:<RADName>_resource"
       }
        """
* print out
```

Executing the scenario returns:

```
"nsName":"fld_1452119626_stage00.rad.<RADName>_.resources:<RADName>_resource
```

In the above scenario 'RADName' is not replaced with the value

Comment: kindly mark this as accepted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52703040/143475

Comment: can you share your example table with at least one row of data?

Comment: input json file:

Comment: I am not able to add complete json because of length. below is the actual row of data   '"nsName": "fld_390974056_stage00.rad.IntegrationFirstRAD_.resources:IntegrationFirstRAD_resource",'

Comment: I'm not able to understand anything in this question, maybe others can.

Comment: Hi Peter, I have updated my summary. Please check once

Comment: @Anupama sorry, this is my response: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @Anupama congratulations, this is much worse. is there someone in your team who can help you make the question more clear ?

Comment: Hi Peter, I have updated the problem space again. Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the [`replace`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#replace) keyword:

```
* def out = { nsName: 'fld_<tenantID>_stage00.rad.<RADName>_.resources:<RADName>_resource' }
* replace out.RADName = 'IntegrationFirstRAD'
* replace out.tenantID = '1452119626'
* match out == { "nsName": "fld_1452119626_stage00.rad.IntegrationFirstRAD_.resources:IntegrationFirstRAD_resource" }
```

You seem to be confused between [embedded expressions](https://github.com/intuit/karate#embedded-expressions) and [`Scenario Outline`s](https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-tests).

I guess it is worth saying this again, you really really really should read the documentation fully once.

Comment: Hi Peter,  This is working perfectly fine. Just a suggestion,  Why can't you start some End to End  training sessions in you tube for beginners.  Video tutorials for each topic in karate really helps many people who are using Karate . This is just a request from Karate fan :)

Comment: @Anupama ok, I'll do this soon !