# Karate how to loop through array and update path param

Tags: karate

I need to do clean up after running my karate tests and invoke a clean up endpoint for all objects i created .
Something of the sort of:

```
for all objects i created:
      invoke rest endpoint path/object.id
```

I followed
[Can we loop feature files and execute using multiple login users in karate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52702359/can-we-loop-feature-files-and-execute-using-multiple-login-users-in-karate)

And also checked
https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/callarray/call-json-array.feature

They allow to pass param in the request but not in the path param. I tried doing:

```
def result = call read(clean-up.feature) ids
```

But this fails as the clean-up.feature needs two params path and id

```
Given Path resourcePath ,  resourceId
```

I also tried

```
Given id: '#(ids)'
And path resourcePath, id
```

and

```
Given path resourcePath,id: '#(ids)'
```

But that doesn't work. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: can you provide sample how does your `ids` looks like?

Comment: its an array 
[
"val1",
  "val4",
  "val5"
]

Comment: url path is something like url/context/val1 , url/context/val4 , url/context/val5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to transform your `ids` to a valid JSON array

```
* def ids = [ "val1", "val4", "val5" ] 
* def ids = karate.mapWithKey(ids, 'id')
* def result = call read(clean-up.feature) ids
```

inside called feature

```
And path 'url' , 'context' , id
```

refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms